# How secure is str(BlobKey)?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I have implemented a generic blob serving handler as mentioned in the [appengine docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Serving_a_Blob).  The handler will serve any blob to you, as long as you know that blob's key string.  I am using it to easily compose URLs that clients can use to download their files.  If client A inspects the URL to download their file and finds their blob key (i.e. `1CX2kh468IDYKGcDUiq5c69u8BRXBtKBYcIaJkmSbSa4QY096gGVaYCZJjGZUpDz == str(BlobKey)`), can they somehow reverse-engineer this key and easily construct another key that can be used to download client B's files?  Or does the key have a random component added?

For reference, there is [this note](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key) about `str(db.Key)`, which is what raises my question:

> Note: The string representation of a key looks cryptic, but is not
>   encrypted! It can be converted back to the raw key data, both kind and
>   identifier. If you don't want to expose this data to your users (and
>   allow them to easily guess other entities' keys), then encrypt these
>   strings or use something else.

I am creating the files like this, which does not specify a `filename` parameter, so I think the question boils down to, how does `create()` "pick" a `filename` when one is not specified? I suppose I could generate a random filename and pass it in here to be doubly sure this is secure.

```
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 2):

BlobKeys are non guessable. If a user has one key, that in no way enables them to guess another key. Unlike datastore keys, which contain full path information, BlobKeys do not encode any such data. You can share them safely without risk of a user doing an attack as you describe.

(I could not locate docs for these claims - this is based on my recollection.)

Comment: Hey, I think this may not be correct. If using image serving url the resulting url is not guessable https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions but the blobkey doesn't seem to have such properties. There seems to be a somewhate cryptic quote "If access to your Blobstore values must be restricted, be careful when serving values based on keys calculated from user-submitted data." https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobkeyclass Let me know if you find out more re security.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a filename when creating a blob:

```
name = .....
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream', _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=name)
```

And you do not need to use str(BlobKey). The BlobKey can be part of your serving url